# How do I access (in Aframe) webGLRenderer.localClippingEnabled?

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to create a local clipping plane in AFrame, essentially this effect
https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_clipping_intersection

To enable the clipping, you must have a reference to the renderer, and enable localClippingEnabled, like this:

```
renderer.localClippingEnabled = true;
```

In AFrame, the webGLRenderer is exposed through a the component renderer, but localClippingEnabled property is not supported. ie

```
<a-scene renderer="localClippingEnabled:true">
```

core:schema:warn Unknown property `localClippingEnabled` for component/system `undefined`.

```
    AFRAME.registerComponent('matclipplane', {
      schema:{
        clipHeight:{type: 'number', default: 1}
      },
      init: function () {
        let el = this.el;
        let self = this;
        self.scene = el.sceneEl.object3D;
        let renderer = THREE.WebGLRenderer; // How to refernence the renderer?
        renderer.localClippingEnabled = true;
```

I've attempted to reference it in a custom component, like this

```
   let renderer = THREE.WebGLRenderer;
   renderer.localClippingEnabled = true;
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. I'm not convinced this is a proper reference to the WebGLRenderer, as logging it in the console does not reveal the property localClippingEnabled.

From what I have seen in THREEjs examples, reference is always  from a newly constructed renderer. So I tried that , and in the console, it looks right, with the localClippingEnable=true in the console, but still doesn't work, because (I don't think) this new renderer is doing the rendering. 
How can I make this work?

Here is my glitch in progress.
https://glitch.com/~clipping-plane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/core/scene.html#properties), you can access the renderer object as a scene property (`sceneEl.renderer`).

---

For example:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', {
   init: function() {
      console.log(this.el.sceneEl.renderer.localClippingEnabled)
      this.el.sceneEl.renderer.localClippingEnabled = true
   }
})
```

Check it out in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/a7yqn3m5/2/) fiddle.

Comment: Thanks Piotr! That fiddle made a big difference, as I could not get a reference to the renderer from within a component attached to an entity inside the scene, but a component attached to the scene works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: It should work with the reference `this.el.sceneEl.renderer` in any component